# Bigquery : combine two columns

Tags: google-bigquery

I am just wondering how can we combine 2 fields in Bigquery.

**This is my SQL**

```
SELECT
 cast(tbl.table_name as string) + '.' + cast(col.column_name as string)
FROM 
xy.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES tbl
INNER JOIN 
xy.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS col
ON tbl.table_name = col.table_name
```

**This is the error I'm getting**

> No matching signature for operator + for argument types: STRING, STRING. Supported signatures: INT64 + INT64; FLOAT64 + FLOAT64; NUMERIC + NUMERIC at [3:2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For BigQuery Standard SQL

You can just use `CONCAT()` function without `CAST`'ing string to string as in below example

```
CONCAT(tbl.table_name, '.', col.column_name)
```

Yet another option is `FORMAT()` function

```
FORMAT('%s.%s', tbl.table_name, col.column_name)
```

Comment: need to check if the value is null for each of the fields otherwise it may result in null if  one is null https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59852764/bigquery-concatenating-stringemptystring-results-in-null-value

Answer (score 2):

You can use concat as defined in this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#concat)

**This is the SQL**

```
SELECT
 CONCAT(cast(tbl.table_name as string), '.',cast(col.column_name as string))
FROM 
`dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` tbl
INNER JOIN 
`dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` col
ON tbl.table_name = col.table_name
```

**Output**

```
+---------------------+
| fo_                 |
+---------------------+
| Table1.col          |
| Table1.col2         |
+---------------------+
```

Comment: Cool. got it. Even with multiple columns. thank you so much. Really appreciated. :)

Comment: @Anush, Your welcome. Can you also vote up and not only accept the answer? It's important to the community and will help you increase your reputation as well

Answer (score 1):

you have two be careful with null values in one of them it may result in null for the concat, use ISNULL to check

```
CONCAT(IFNULL(col1, ''), "-", IFNULL(col2, ''))
```

see [BigQuery - Concatenating String+EmptyString results in NULL value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59852764/bigquery-concatenating-stringemptystring-results-in-null-value)