# BigQuery - Concatenating String+EmptyString results in NULL value

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two string type fields "Source" and "Detail" with either of this having null value. Now I'm concatenating both the string fields separated by hyphen(-); but due to NULL value, the output is also NULL.

Refer image consisting of the actualoutput and outputexpected (highlighted yellow).

Can someone please suggest how to get the output expected?

[image]

**Query I used:**

SELECT Source, Detail, CONCAT(cast(Source as string), "-", cast(Detail as string)) AS actualoutput FROM `tablename`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT Source, Detail, CONCAT(IFNULL(Source, ''), "-", IFNULL(Detail, '')) AS actualoutput 
FROM tablename
```

Note: as both "Source" and "Detail" are already of type STRING - you can omit CAST'ing to STRING

Answer (score 4):

Use `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` with empty string:

```
SELECT
    Source,
    Detail,
    CONCAT(COALESCE(Source, ''), '-', COALESCE(Detail, '')) AS actualoutput
FROM tablename;
```

Note that anything concatenated with `NULL` will always yield `NULL`.